# How to fix Access Denied: The Personal Access Token used has expired

Tags: azure-devops

We are running into "Access Denied: The Personal Access Token used has expired.", we have PAT that is still valid.

Any idea what might be happening?

```
    id: "1"
    errorCode: 0
    eventId: 3000
    innerException: null
    message: "Access Denied: The Personal Access Token used has expired."
    typeKey: "PipelineValidationException"
    typeName: "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi"
```

I am not sure which token is expired, how can I find?

[image]

Comment: Where did you encounter this error? Please add the details of the context in your question.

Comment: which task and logs can you share more on specific step ?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: It was a downstream integration which was failing, we had checkmarx integration, which was running into an issue and the whole thing was masked by this error.

Answer (score 0):

> How to fix Access Denied: The Personal Access Token used has expired

The direct way to check whether the PAT token has expired is to find the place where PAT is used in the pipeline, find the name of the PAT, and then check whether it has expired.

Besides, if you could not find it in the pipeline, you could go to the Personal Access Tokens:

[image]

Then check the **Expires on** column.